# can't get the objects of foreign keys of django models also my design is probably bad

Tags: python, django, model, foreign-keys

I've made two django models: Person and Items (here is part of my code):

```
class Person(models.Model):
    """ Represent a person who has credentials. The person may have
    devices and/or accessories. """ 

    #basic information
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

class Item(models.Model):
""" Represents a device or accessory. """  
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Person)
```

Basically, I need to have one person have the potential to own multiple items. I need to be able to check whether or not an owner has an item and then I also need to be able to check if an item currently has an owner. I can't work with the variable owner because it's a foreign key. Or maybe I'm solving this problem incorrectly?

If I'm approaching this wrong, I need to be able to store a database of items and owners, with owners having multiple items, and I should be able to know who has what items.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to declare Person before Item
Also you might want to use a [ManyToMany](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) relationship instead of a ForeignKey

```
class Item(models.Model):
""" Represents a device or accessory. """  
    name = models.models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Person(models.Model):
""" Represent a person who has credentials. The person may have
    devices and/or accessories. """ 

    #basic information
    name = models.models.CharField(max_length=50)
    item = models.ManyToManyField(Item)
```

So basically you were doing it backwards. 
So you create an object Item:

```
item = Item.objects.create(name='itemname')
```

And you add it to a person object:

```
person = Person.objects.get(name="the person's name")
person.add(item)
person.save
```

This should work

Comment: Person is before item. I copy pasted it backwards.

Comment: Edit your post then! And take a look at the many to many relationship, that's what you want to use if person can have several (many) items

Comment: I seriously just learned Django today. Can you just help me get a solution to this?

Comment: I like what you have posted, but where do I enter in your second segment about item = Item.objects.create.. etc etc? I've been using the ForeignKey as a drop down so that you can select an item to add.

Comment: then add an id field to your item model which you set as the primary key. That primary key that you will use in your drop down. So you create all your items with id and name. Instantiate your drop down. And once you're in the views you get the item `Item.objects.get(id=id)` and add it to the person as written in my answer.
Read the doc about manytomany relationships, it'll help!